# Thunderbird - Have 2 gmail accounts - want to see each calendar independent of the other

Tags: thunderbird, gmail, calendar

Our company has just switched from exchange to GSuite.  I already have my personal email and calendar and I use Thunderbird.  I added my work email to Thunderbird.  I would like to be able to open calendar and either have it show my work calendar OR my personal calendar - but NOT both merged.  I cannot seem to figure out how to do this.  It seems to be one and all has to be on that one - as opposed to mail where it shows me my 2 email accounts and I can open whichever one for whom I want to see the email.

Comment: You need to use different profiles: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/using-multiple-profiles